# Keyboard layout grayed out?

Tags: keyboard

I tried installing the Logitech keyboard layout using [this guide](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071102162602375).

It appears in the Language Menu, so I added it as a possible layout, but it is grayed out in the Input menu so I can't switch to it.

[image: Input menu with grayed out layout]

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.3. I downloaded the Logitech layout file from their website, version 3.9.3.

Any idea what the cause of this could be and what I can do to make it work? I have no idea what else to search for to fix this issue.

Comment: Did the layout file you tried to install have .keylayout at the end of its name?

Comment: Hmm nope, it had a rsrc at the end of its name. That's what the guide said to copy over?

Comment: It might work better just to install the .keylayout file.  I can send you one if you want (tom at bluesky dot org)